# Gradlew lint execution failed for task kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, lint

I'm currently trying to setup CI/CD for my project and would like to have it run lint when ever it builds the `develop` branch (stopping the build if there are unhandled lint issues). In order for this to work right, I need to have a lint-baseline.xml generate, as well as to be able to run lint locally before I push to `develop`. I am currently having an issue on more than one project where the lint task crashes with the following results:

```
C:\path\to\project>gradlew lintDebug

> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
e: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:51)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.plugins.ServiceLoaderLite.loadImplementations(ServiceLoaderLite.kt:44)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension$loadProcessors$efficientProcessorLoader$1.doLoadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:83)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors(ProcessorLoader.kt:45)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorLoader.loadProcessors$default(ProcessorLoader.kt:28)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.loadProcessors(Kapt3Extension.kt:88)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:171)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:98)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:97)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:557)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:82)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:107)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:548)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:177)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:165)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:84)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:42)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1558)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 43 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
41 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 38 up-to-date
```

This has frustrated me greatly and I have been trying to find a fix for this. I've also tried this in a "plain" android app project and I get an almost identical error. The following is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    /** WARNING There is currently a warning about using Result, we may have to use Promise at a future point   ***/
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental"]
    }
    lintOptions {
        baseline file("lint-baseline.xml")
        abortOnError false
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

dependencies {
    // region Project Includes
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // endregion

    // region Android Framework
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // endregion

    // region Kotlin Framework
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // region Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutine_version"
    // endregion
    // endregion

    // region ReactiveX
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.2.0'

    // region Testing framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:0.43"
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0' // Robolectric environment
    testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.9.1' //For timeline version, see: https://mockk.io
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    // endregion
}
```

At one point I found a forum saying that I needed to add the JAXB library, I'm not sure what is using it though in my Kotlin only project. I am using Databinding in my layouts, I'm not sure if that could be a part of the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!